# Ubuntu Disk Space

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

there
I'm a rookie in both Ubuntu and Linux. I was trying to figure out the meaning of what each partition means. So, I would say sorry if I asked any stupid questions.

First question is, with respect to the screenshots below, I have 39.5GB available for /home. But, it shows /home has 189GB in System Monitor. So, can someone please tell me what does this mean?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnm2O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0loE2.png)

Second question is, can I install software in /dev/sda5 instead of /dev/sda3?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: I figured it out. Thx for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are used to windows, to ease the transition you can think of the mount-points as partitions.  In Linux, the partitions don't have drive letters, rather they have mount points which you access just like any other folder.  Your /home mount does indeed have 189gb, meaning that everything you put into a users folder, or anything you put into any folder under /home will use some of that 189gb bucket of storage and not any of the other.  Your /etc partiton (which is where most of your system files such as network config etc are stored) is what the "device" having 39.5 gigs available is referencing.  If you want to install programs to the /home partition, you can either move their folders from their default location to a new folder in /home and then use a symlink (read on the 'link' command) or if you have a managing application (such as Steam for Games) you can configure it to use a subfolder of /home for its storage location.